# API endpoint that accepts files: multipart form data VS contents as base 64 String

Tags: rest, http

I know this is not a new question, but I would like to rephrase this question to answer my concern.

When asked about this question, a common answer is to use "multipart form data". However, we can alternatively send the binary data as a base 64 String on a normal JSON/XML/whatever field ([Mandrill does it](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html)) .

I'm mainly concerned about big files and efficiency in uploading. With this in mind, is there any advantage in using "multipart form data" instead of encoding the contents as a base 64 String? Is there anything else I could be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are really concerned about efficiency I'd use a compression format first. Multipart form data is useful when you either have to send multiple documents at once or have to attach additional information. If you are just interested in the upload of a file, the most efficient method is to upload the file directly. Base64 is more or less used to have a further layer of transmission check. It [does not reduce the actual file size](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119181/what-type-of-encoding-can-i-use-to-make-a-string-shorter) nor does it provide any security benefits

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner. That's a very good answer, at least for what I was looking for. I I'm afraid I can't still upvote your comment with my reputation level.